# Why is a side of a Talmudic page called "amud"?

Tags: talmud-gemara, language

On some occasions, I have heard one side of a Talmudic page called **tzad** meaning "side".

The more common term I have heard is **amud** meaning "pillar". Why is that term used, and when did this term first appear in usage?

Comment: Pillar=Column. There is one column of talmud text per side of a page

Comment: At least in modern Hebrew, amud means page. Though I don’t know how old that meaning is; it may come from the fact that the side of a gemara is called an amud.

Comment: Like @NoachMiFrankfurt said. There are two columns of text on each page, one column on each side. 'amud' refers to the columns of text, not to the sides of the page. Infrequently you may see references to other sefarim using ע״ג and ע״ד, where there are two columns of text per side, and the reference identifies columns on side B.